# Scan items from a query with multiple columns of the same name

Tags: mysql, go, sqlx

**I have a query like**

```
myQuery := "SELECT DISTINCT table1.id, table1.active, table2.active FROM table1 INNER JOIN table 2 ON table1.id = table2.foreign_id AND table2.active = true
```

**and I'm working with MySQL**.

I have to select `table2.active` to avoid the `SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT in my sql` error.

I'm using `sqlx` but I figure the problems lie deeper. I can't scan the result into a target object with `err := conn.Unsafe().Select(dest, myQuery)`, with `dest` of type `interface{}` being a pointer to an interface slice, because of two aspects:

1. As far as I can tell the `Columns` from `sql.Rows` don't hold the qualifiers in their names, so I've gotten basically two `Columns` whose names are just `active`, without `table1` or `table2`. This means, `table2.active` overrides `table1.active` when scanned into the target structure.
2. Let's also assume that `table1.active` has another type than `table2.active` (which doesn't make much sense in this simple example but it does in my real scenario). I'd get an error because the `table2.active` value would have the wrong type to be scanned into my target object.

Since I don't know the nature of the structs in `dest`, going over the `Rows` directly doesn't help much since it feels impossible to write those values into the `dest` struct manually. I can get all field names of the target structs with some reflections and put them into the `SELECT` part of the query (that's what I'm doing actually), but not really the other way around.

I'm also wondering whether I could make the query above a subquery, wrapping it into an outer query without all the misleading columns. But a query like `SELECT id, active FROM table1 WHERE id IN ([query above])` wouldn't work with all those other columns returned as well.
Maybe I can gather the ids manually and run a second query, but that's probably rather ineffective.

Comment: Why can't you just use an alias? `table2.active as active2 FROM table1...`

Comment: @Strawberry I expected that the name in the `SELECT` part must match the name in the `JOIN` condition due to that MySQL restriction (`SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT in my sql error`). But after a first short test it seem's that't not the case. OMG ... that would be too easy! :D Thanks! In case you post an answer I'ld gladly accept it!

Comment: Feel free to answer (and then accept) your own question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strawberry just gave the solution in the comments: Even columns required in the `SELECT` clause to prevent the `SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT in my sql error` error can be aliased. So basically

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.id, table1.active, table2.active as active2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table 2 ON table1.id = table2.foreign_id AND table2.active = true
```

does the trick - the MySQL error will disappear, but that column does not get in the way of the scanner!